# string,char comparison in c++

Tags: c++, string, char, ascii, string-comparison

*Hello!
I'm making program where user enters a sentence and program 
prints out how many letters there are in a sentence(Capital and non-capital).
I made a program but it prints out weird results.Please help as soon as possible. :)

```
include <iostream>
include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
  {
string Sent;

 cout << "Enter a sentence !"<<endl;
 cin>>Sent;

    for(int a=0;a<Sent.length();a++){

        if (96<int(Sent[a])<123 || 64<int(Sent[a])<91){
           cout << "this is letter"<< endl;
        }else{
            cout << "this is not letter"<< endl;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: `a<b<c`: C++ doesn't work like that.

Comment: Could you please append the "weird result"?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will get one and only one word. `cin >> Sent` won't extract the whole line. You have to use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in order to do this.

Second, you should use [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) or [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) instead to check whether a character is whitespace/an alphanumeric symbol.

Third, `a < b < c` is essentially the same as `(a < b) < c`, which isn't what you meant (`a < b && b < c`) at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with std::alpha:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string Sent;

    cout << "Enter a sentence !"<<endl;
    //cin >> Sent;
    std::getline (std::cin,Sent);
    int count = 0;

     for(int a=0;a<Sent.length();a++){
        if (isalpha(Sent[a])
        {
          count ++;
         }
      }
      cout << "total number of chars " << count <<endl;

  }
```

It is better to use `getline` than using `cin>>` if your input contains whitespace.

Comment: *"It is better to use getline than using cin if your input contains whitespace."* Nah. It's better to use `getline` _on_ `cin`, since `operator>>` stops on whitespaces. Both operate on `cin` ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (96<int(Sent[a])<123 || 64<int(Sent[a])<91){
```

This is wrong.You can't compare using this notation.
You must do:

```
if( Sent[a] > 96 && Sent[a] < 122 || ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (96 < Sent[a] && Sent[a]<123 || 64 < Sent[a] && Sent[a]<91)
```

This is what you want, because:

```
96<int(Sent[a])<123
```

Will evaluate `96<int(Sent[a]),` as bool, then, will compare it (that is 0 or 1) with 123.

Answer (score 0):

This line

`if (96<int(Sent[a])<123 || 64<int(Sent[a])<91)`

must be something like this

`if ((96<int(Sent[a]) && int(Sent[a])<123) || (64<int(Sent[a]) && int(Sent[a])<91))`

but I suggest using the function `isalpha()` defined in the `cctype` header file.